# Can a groovy stand-alone script use gradle libraries?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a groovy project which I've recently converted to building with `gradle` instead of `groovyc`. This necessitated moving the dependences from Grapes to the build.gradle. For example, I know have:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.192'
}
```

However, the original groovy project worked with a helper script `project.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
groovy -cp $DIR/lib/Project.jar $DIR/project.groovy $@
```

And then on the command like do:

```
project.sh -a arg1 -b arg2 pos1 pos2
```

I can easily change the classpath to `$DIR/build/classes/groovy/main`, however, without the `@Grapes(@Grab(group='com.amazonaws', module='aws-java-sdk', version='1.11.192'))` groovy doesn't know where to find the `com.amazonaws` library.

I found the library in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.192/cddbcbe1324564482de639d55999329c02e61ecc/aws-java-sdk-1.11.192.jar` but adding that to the classpath feels like the wrong way to go. What if I change library versions? What about all the libraries that I'm not including in this example?

Is there a way to have my groovy script use the gradle libraries, or is there a way to run my groovy script from within a gradle task and still be able to pass in all my command line arguments. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
gradle runProject -Pprops=$@
```

and

```
task runScript(dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
  main = "project"
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  args project.getProperty('props')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to build a fat jar with your dependencies included, see https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/